# Retrieve Size of User profiles with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm Trying to retrieve the exact size of the profile in windows machine.

below is my code and O/P

```
$profiles = Get-ChildItem C:\Users | ?{Test-path C:\Users\$_\NTUSER.DAT} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
  foreach($profile in $profiles)
    {
    $largeprofile = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\$profile  -recurse | Measure-Object -Sum length | Select -ExpandProperty Sum
    $largeprofile = [math]::Round(($largeprofile/1MB),2) + "MB"
    if($largeprofile -lt 20){Continue}
    $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $profile
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Size(MB)" -Value $largeprofile
    ($object | fl | Out-String).Trim();Write-Output "`n"
    }
```

> O/P
>
> Name     : admin
>
> Size(MB) : 34.62

however exact size of the folder is 181MB,powershell is not able to read all the folders and files inside the parent folder, how can I get the exact size which is displayed in a properties of the folder.

Note : For Folders other than the profile folder o/p is correct.

Comment: Do you have the permissions to check this i.e. running as admin? You didn't mention access denied errors. Also I would tack on a `-Force` to `Get-ChildItem` which finds hidden and readonly stuff (pretty sure)

Comment: Yes, I am using account which has highest privileges.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to add the parameter `-Force` to `Get-ChildItem` when you are Recursing the directory. From the docs [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6#optional-parameters) the `-Force` parameter:

> Allows the cmdlet to get items that cannot otherwise not be accessed
>   by the user, such as hidden or system files.

Additionally, you will want to add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` so you don't get flooded with `Access Denied` errors. These changes makes your code look like this:

```
$profiles = Get-ChildItem C:\Users | ?{Test-path C:\Users\$_\NTUSER.DAT} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
  foreach($profile in $profiles)
    {
    $largeprofile = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\$profile -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Sum length | Select -ExpandProperty Sum
    $largeprofile = [math]::Round(($largeprofile/1MB),2) + "MB"
    if($largeprofile -lt 20){Continue}
    $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $profile
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Size(MB)" -Value $largeprofile
    ($object | fl | Out-String).Trim();Write-Output "`n"
    }
```

Comment: If you're ignoring access denied errors, you're not getting accurate information..

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 does bring up a good point that you should be aware of the files that you cannot access. But the problem would be that you would need to edit permissions in order to see them. If you do run the script ignoring access denied errors, then the number will match what you see in File Explorer.

Comment: @HAL9256 : I already tried with -Force, and the problem is I am not able to access all the files and folders, you mentioned that I will get access denied errors which is correct, is there any way I can manage to provide permission in a script only so I can access all the files andfolders.    I am already using account which has highest privileges in the system to run the script.

Comment: If you are trying to get a general idea of folder sizes, using the `-Force` Running as Administrator will get you 95% of the right answer which is usually "good enough". To get exact sizes and count the access denied files require changing permissions. Even though you are an Administrator, you can get Access Denied for files/folders that you don't have permissions or are not an owner on. e.g. especially with user profiles, there are some files that the file permissions only contain the user, and no administrator group, and the owner is that user.