# Powershell: Get Size of Windows User Directory (C:\Users\<UserName>)

Tags: powershell

I need to get the size of all user folders across 200 VMs. I need -force to see the hidden folders of other users.

```
$objFSO = New-Object -com  Scripting.FileSystemObject 
"{0:N2}" -f (($objFSO.GetFolder("C:\users").Size) / 1MB) + " MB"
```

Works fine for C:\Temp, for example, but returns 0.00 MB for C:\Users, even on my local, where I am an admin.

```
Get-ChildItem -path c:\users -force -recurse | Measure-Object length -sum
```

Throws security exceptions--even on my own user folder, with admin, running in an elevated PS session.

```
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\YuriPup\Documents\My Music:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve Size of User profiles with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54539189/retrieve-size-of-user-profiles-with-powershell)

Comment: What I failed to realize is the errors that were being thrown did not change the size being returned. 

These scripts will throw errors on the directory junctions (aliases, in my understanding) so that while \Users\<username> throws scary looking errors, it's only because it's the junction point and not a "real" problem. 

The output will match a right click, properties for folder size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reason to stress out over this or do it from scratch (unless it's a learning exercise). There are many examples all over the web showing how to do this. There are even pre-built modules you can use from the MS powershellgallery.com, that you can install directly.

```
Find-Module -Name '*folder*' | Format-Table -AutoSize

Version Name                   Repository Description                                                                                                               
------- ----                   ---------- -----------                                                                                                               
1.6.8   PSFolderSize           PSGallery  This module enables you to gather folder size information, and output the results easily in various ways. GitHub Repo: ...
1.3.1   GetSTFolderSize        PSGallery  Get folder sizes blazingly fast, with the Svendsen Tech Get-STFolderSize function. Also measures and displays how long ...
1.0     cEPRSFolderPermissions PSGallery  cEPRSFolderPermissions Module helps in providing the required permissions for a User to the respective Folder             
1.0.4   FolderBookmarks        PSGallery  The module provides functions to manage and use bookmarks that point to folders.                                          
1.0     cFolderQuota           PSGallery  DSC Resource for Creating Quotas and Quotas Templates                                                                     
1.0.0.0 ExplorerFolder         PSGallery  Manages the Explorer Shell                                                                                                
2.0.0   FolderEncoder          PSGallery  Encode files from folder for(for example) uploading to cloud                                                              
1.0     DeleteSearchFolders    PSGallery  Module used for finding and deleting Search folders from an Exchange Mailbox                                              
1.0.3   Illallangi.MailFolders PSGallery  Manage Outlook Folders
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this script? you can get the directory size with gci command.

`'{0:N2} GB' -f ((gci –force C:\Users\$directoryName –Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| measure Length -s).sum / 1Gb)`

same you can loop for all users in `c:\users` directory and execute it on given list of  remote machines.

```
# List of servers
$Computers = @("Machine1", "Machine2", "Machine3")   

#Start all jobs in parallel 
ForEach($Computer in $Computers) 
{ 
   Write-Host $Computer 

   $Depth = 1
   $Path = 'C:\Users\'

$Levels = '/*' * $Depth
Get-ChildItem -Directory $Path/$Levels |

ForEach-Object 
{ 
   $name = ($_.FullName -split '[\\/]')[-$Depth] 
   #Write-Host $name;
   $wmidiskblock = "'{0:N2} GB' -f ((gci –force C:\Users\$name –Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| measure Length -s).sum / 1Gb)";
   Write-Host $wmidiskblock;
} 

   Start-Job -scriptblock $wmidiskblock  -ArgumentList $Computer 

} 

Get-Job | Wait-Job 

$out = Get-Job | Receive-Job 
$out |export-csv 'c:\temp\result.csv'
```